# How two pin plugs work irrespective of the way they are inserted?

Tags: plug

I recently got a Phone and it came with a Two pin power cable:
[image: HTC One Charger]
My phone charges irrepective of the way this Charger inserted in power socket.
AFAIK, Socket has polarity. One is +ve and another is -ve.

How this charger charges my phone even if I interchange polarity?

Electronics Engineer in me says, Device should not work if I connect +ve to -ve and vice versa!

Comment: Are your home wall sockets marked "live" and "neutral", because mine are not? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: You're not referring to the AC adapter are you?

Comment: -1 for a total failure of googling / basic research / reading the words on the charger.

Comment: Don't they teach the difference between AC and DC in Electronics 001?

Comment: Oops!! Got the point!! Sorry!! * Jumps in the well *

Comment: No offense but how did you become "Graduated with degree of Electronics Engineering"? Or maybe I totally missed the point of the question.

Comment: @Rev1.0 Me to Wondering now ;-)

Comment: Nevermind, you probably asked that before you had your first coffee ;)

Comment: @Rev1.0 That's actually true... Posted this question and then gone for a Coffee... And when Returned, I had lot of notifications!

Comment: AC power jacks are the most common symmetrical connector, but symmetrical connectors are used for some other purposes as well.  Often they're used for circuits which have no inherent polarization; occasionally they may be used in places with circuitry that can adapt to either direction of insertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternating current (AC) supply has a voltage that alternates from positive to negative 50 or 60 times a second. So each pin is alternately positive and then negative.

Almost all domestic power outlets in the world are AC.

The orientation can have safety implications as there is a policy to have fuses and switches in the wire considered "live" or "hot" and not in the wire considered "neutral". The "neutral" wire in the supply is usually connected to "ground"/"earth" at the power station or at entry to a building. This probably is of no consequence for double insulated appliances (which should be marked as such)

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is really about AC, it's worth remembering you CAN pull this stunt with a DC supply, if you interpose a bridge rectifier between supply and appliance.

It's not commonly done because of the voltage drop across 2 diodes; and the single diode used for "reverse voltage protection" is often more loss than you want.

However there may be some cases where having the appliance not merely *survive* but actually *work as normal* on a reversed supply is worth the voltage loss. Old cars where you may occasionally come across a "positive earth" model may be one example; or an environment where you can't trust users to choose the right polarity of wall wart...